# filter django serializer data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Many time we access data via serializer directory according to relationship defined in models in Django(1.11.10). How can i set a filter like fetch-only is_active=1.

```
class DaasJobsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DaasJobs
        fields = '__all__'

class DaasScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    jobs = DaasJobsSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DaasSchedule
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here i just want to set a filter to fetch only those Jobs which db field is_active=1 in this line like that **DaasJobsSerializer(read_only=True,many=True, filter={"is_active":1}) how to do something like this ??**

Currently it is giving me all the data without checking is_active,
and i dont want to create serializerMethodField for that.. because all methods written earlier.. i am just setting a is_active field later in the tables in db.

Comment: Filtering is something you do on the `ViewSet` level, and you can use a `Prefetch` object to "patch" the related objects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for your reply, but how can i use Prefetch object while accessing data via serializer(jobs = DaasJobsSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do it via serializers you can try overriding the `ListSerializer` and passing it as a custom [`list_serializer_class`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior).

```
class IsActiveListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(is_active=1)
        return super().to_representation(data)
```

In your serializer:

```
class DaasJobsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DaasJobs
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = IsActiveListSerializer  # import it here
```

Of course this is a specific use-case, you could make a more generalized version of the ListSerializer to:

```
class FilteredListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    filter_kwargs = {}

    def to_representation(self, data):
        if not self.filter_kwargs or not isinstance(self.filter_kwargs, dict):
            raise TypeError(_('Invalid Attribute Type: `filter_kwargs` must be a of type `dict`.'))
        data = data.filter(**self.filter_kwargs)
        return super().to_representation(data)
```

And then you could sub-class that to make other specific ListSerializers such as:

```
 class IsActiveListSerializer(FilteredListSerializer):
     filter_kwargs = {'is_active': 1}
```

and many others...

Comment: awesome solution to my problem, Thanks!! Here i just wanna ask you how can i explore these kinds of new solutions in for me in Django, did you know the solution already ? if not then how was your approach to find this awesome solution above. how can i improve my django skills to find the solution of any problem.

Comment: I keep learning new things everyday as well. You'll always find something new in the docs. And there's no better way than to keep practising. With regards to this, I learnt it when I was working on a real project and had this exact need. Google, stackoverflow and docs are all great resources